# How To Transpose / Convert Columns And Rows Into Single Column oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

How could you convert or transpose a range of data into a single column as shown above? Values could be ambiguous in data but output should contain unique values only.

Comment: Where shown above ? You forgot to post the expected result and dataset

Comment: I uploaded images but its not showing...how to do it?

Comment: Dont upload any images as its not visible to most of the user. Try to write it in the question.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

(Updated after more information was provided in comments)

If your initial data comes from a query you could use a [common table expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) to do this:

```
with query_results (a,b,c) as ( 
   ... your original query that you have not shown us goes here ...
)
select a
from query_results
union 
select b 
from query_results
union
select c
from query_results
order by 1
```

The `UNION` operator will remove duplicates from the output

Comment: Thanks...the_table is query resultset in my case...will it run the query each time in case of union? If yes...Is der any other way to do it?

Comment: @test500: you should have added that important piece of information with your question. It's not considered polite to reveal more details after you have received an answer. See my edit

Comment: Sorry for that...Thanks again...Now will it run the query only once in updated reply?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT value
FROM   your_table
UNPIVOT ( value FOR type IN ( a, b, c ) );
```